# Mysql select from two tables,get all datas,make num 0 if not exist

Tags: mysql, join, select

table a:

```
name
a
e
```

table b:

```
name   num
   a    10
   b    20
   c    30
```

i want to get :

```
name    num
a   10
b   20
c   30
e   0
```

My sql sentence is ：

```
select c.name,
IFNULL (b.num,0) as 'num'
from
(select name from a
union 
select name from b) c
left join b
on c.`name`=b.`name`
```

is there other way to get this result more simple？

Comment: What you really want here is a full outer join.  But, since MySQL does not support it, you have to resort to something like using a union query, which you are already doing.

Comment: thank you !can you tell me what is the sql sentence if using a full outer join.

Comment: Actually, given that the A table doesn't have any numerical data, a union with an aggregation might work better than a full outer join, q.v. my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FULL OUTER JOIN can be achieve by below in mysql 

SELECT a.name, IFNULL (b.num,0) as 'num' FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.name = a.name
UNION
SELECT b.name, IFNULL (b.num,0) as 'num' FROM a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to simulate a full outer join here, but a subquery on a union between the two tables could also work:

```
SELECT name, SUM(num) AS num
FROM
(
    SELECT name, 0 AS num FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, num FROM tableB
) t
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, can you know why you are using SUM(num), instead of getting of table b name and num columns

Comment: @Krishna It is a math trick.  I am logically assigning a number of zero to the first table.  This means that if a given name be present in both tables, the first occurrence won't affect the number reported.